# Which enemies was Rav Huna running away from?

Tags: history, talmud-gemara, maseches-pesachim, talmud-yerushalmi, amoroim

[Yerushalmi, Pesachim 1.1](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Jerusalem_Talmud_Pesachim.1b.1?vhe=Mechon_Mamre_Talmud_Yerushalmi&lang=en):

> דאמר רב הונא כד הוינן ערקין באילין בוטיתא דסדרא רבה היו מדליקין עלינו
> נרות בשעה שהיו כיהים היינו יודעין שהוא יום ובשעה שהיו מבהיקין היינו
> יודעין שהוא לילה

The Talmud describes Rav Huna on the run and in hiding in a sort of cave/ruin. The commentaries on the page say he was running from enemies. Who were these enemies?

Comment: Antisémites?,..,

Comment: It's mentioned here: https://www.chevrahlomdeimishnah.org/2008/3.Bo.pdf.  It does not say who the enemies were, but provides fascinating insights drawn from that episode.

Comment: @MauriceMizrahi however, the extra details are only those of the commentaries.

Comment: The Good Manners Society? :-)  https://www.tabletmag.com/jewish-life-and-religion/145223/daf-yomi-50

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Rabbi Ze'ev Yaavetz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ze%27ev_Yavetz) in [Toldot Yisrael, Vol. 7, pp. 185](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=36982&st=&pgnum=188)-[186](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=36982&st=&pgnum=189), the enemies were the Christians (minim) who were now secretly part of the Roman government, in the days of [Emperor Diocletian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diocletian) (although Diocletian himself had a mostly positive attitude towards the Jews, so perhaps he means during the first days of Constantine, prior to his actual conversion to Christianity?).

This Rav Huna is identified by Rabbi Yaavetz as [Rabbi Huna the Kohen](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A8%D7%91_%D7%94%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%90_(%D7%94%D7%9B%D7%94%D7%9F)), student of Rabbi Abahu. The more famous Rav Huna, student of Rav, did not live in Eretz Yisrael. Note that this story is also mentioned in [Beresheet Rabbah 31:11](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Bereishit_Rabbah.31.11?vhe=Midrash_Rabbah_--_TE&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) and [Yalkut Shimoni on the Torah 53:2](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Yalkut_Shimoni_on_Torah.53.2?vhe=Yalkut_Shimoni_on_Torah&lang=en).